# TypeError when try to install Anaconda

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

I try to install Anaconda on Ubuntu-18. 
I've download instalation script from:
https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/

When I run script installation stop after some time and give me error:

```
[...]
Extracting : tqdm-4.32.1-py_0.tar.bz2:  76%|███████▋  | 220/288 [00:11<00:25,  2.63it/s]Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
  File "threading.py", line 864, in run
  File "concurrent/futures/process.py", line 272, in _queue_management_worker
  File "multiprocessing/connection.py", line 251, in recv
  File "pickle.py", line 1558, in _loads
  File "pickle.py", line 1050, in load
  File "pickle.py", line 1398, in load_reduce
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'msg'
```

I've no idea what should I do to install Anaconda correctly

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Comment: Not the fix, but have you tried the "64-Bit (x86) Installer (517 MB)" or "64-Bit (Power8 and Power9) Installer (326 MB)" installers available?

Comment: 2nd option, I'll try 517 verison

Comment: With 64-Bit (x86) Installer (517 MB) it work , thank, solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to  download "64-Bit (x86) Installer (517 MB)" as @Elias Kassell said

Comment: I tried all 3 distribution (actuall 2 - DOWNLOAD Button and 64 (x86) are the same) and still got this error :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error due to `python` was not recognized.

Check if you have python installed using:

```
python --version
```

if python is not recognized but you have any other python app installed (i.e. python3.7) modify your ~/.bashrc and add:

```
alias python=python3.7
```

if you have not python installed, use `sudo apt install python` to proceed.